# Unable to load component using location redirection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm trying load a page by changing the location as below in AppComponent ngOnInit()

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/somepage';
```

somepage.module.ts is

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { routing } from './somepage.routing';
import { SomepageComponent } from './somepage.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        SomepageComponent
    ]
})
export class SomepageModule { }
```

somepage.component.ts is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: '<p>Loading...</p>',
})

export class SomepageComponent {    
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("finshed")
    }
}
```

app.routing.ts is

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SomepageComponent} from './somepage.component';

export const routes: Routes = [    
    { path: 'somepage', component:SomepageComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

in the console I can see the log **Navigated to http://localhost:3000/somepage**

but I can't see the log saying **finshed** or any other console errors.

I don't know what is going on. I did also try with debugger, I got nothing. What is going wrong here?

Comment: So, why do you do that, instead of using `router.navigate(...)`?

Comment: that's the requirement.

Comment: Weird requirement. I'm pretty sure this won't work. `window.location.href` will just reload the page. You need to modify the browser code to get that working. If you use `router.navigate()` then the router is using `pushState()` which supports changing the URL without reloading the page.